# Setting up collider for Maze structure

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]I have two mazes one in Blender and another in Unity which was built using ProBuilder.
I can use either one of them, but the problem is I can't set the collider on any of them mesh collider isn't working correctly.
The maze which was built by ProBuilder has mesh in the mesh collider component but my player still falls through.

If there is a better way please let me know. Thank you

I have convex ticked to show collider.

Comment: Is the mesh collider you are using convex? Also, is your maze mesh (the one from blender) a solid object or is it missing any faces?

Comment: yes, I did remove faces and added some meshes. I tried a few things actually mesh collider with convex and rigidbody(read online that they need to go together) and tried without convex as well. I have a feeling I cannot remove faces ?

Comment: I have no idea how the mesh collider interacts with missing faces, but I can imagine this may confuse the physics engine. One thing to check, though, is that your player character is not using a mesh collider. Mesh colliders don't interact with other mesh colliders (unless they are convex, but convex will not be able to accurately describe a maze). If your player character is using a mesh collider, this would be the issue, and I would suggest creating a collider for them out of primitives.

Comment: My player is not using a mesh collider. Though even without missing faces unity is having a hard time setting up a mesh collider for my maze

Comment: Can you please upload some screenshots of how you set it up, and how Unity draws the collider when you have your maze selected?

Comment: I have added the screenshot. I hope this is what you were talking about. If not let me know I will upload more screenshot

Comment: Can you simply confirm if your player object is using any form of collider? Because if it isn't, it cannot collide. On another note; convex is not used for 'showing the collider'

Comment: Yes Yes My player has Rigidbody and Capsule Collider both

Answer (score 0):

Having a convex collider on the entire maze is like putting the entire maze in a cardboard box. It's not going to work. You need to deconstruct the maze to the point that you have wall segments, and then you can put convex colliders on each wall segment.

I don't see a rigidbody in the screenshot you posted. There might be a chance you could clear the convex setting on the collider, add a Rigidbody, and use the `isKinematic` setting on the Rigidbody and get what you want.

Really though, if I were you, I'd deconstruct the map to wall segments, represent your map with an array, and dynamically create the maze in `Awake` (which triggers [before Start](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)). This also allows you to put colliders on the floor and wall segments individually, lets you easily create different mazes, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ticket convex collider to show how collider is formed I have it unticked otherwise. I tried that with ProBuilder extension floor and stairs work but I can pass through the maze wall though. But I will try the way you explained and see If I can get it to work.